# Hadoop0.20.2, Hive0.10

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am using hadoop0.20.2 and trying to install Hive 0.10.0 on top of it. 
I am getting the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hive/conf/HiveConf
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:149)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 3 more
```

I did not find a solution from a similar question which was answered earlier.
I am posting this as a new one.Please find the classpath details:

```
HADOOP_HOME - /project/hadoop-0.20.2    
HIVE_HOME - /project/hive-0.10.0    
HADOOP_CLASSPATH - /project/hadoop-0.20.2/lib:/project/hive-0.10.0/lib/*.jar
```

Spent a lot of time on this. Any help will be greatly appreciated.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Although Hive 0.10.0 works with Hadoop 0.20.x, you should avoid using such an old release.

Are you really using hyphen(-) in your export statements? Or is it just here? Ideally these 3 exports should be enough to get Hive running :

```
export HADOOP_HOME=/project/hadoop-0.20.2
export HIVE_HOME=/project/hive-0.10.0
export PATH=$HIVE_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

How are you exporting these variables? Adding these statements in `~/.bashrc` works fine. And, do not forget to source it after these changes,

```
source ~/.bashrc
```